# Is there another style for writing LIKE queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I write some queries like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample.dbo.Temp
WHERE
   Name LIKE '%ab%'
OR Name LIKE '%fg%'
OR NAME LIKE '%asd%'
OR ...
OR ...
OR Name LIKE '%kj%'
```

Is there anyway I can rewrite this query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sample.dbo.Temp
WHERE
   Name LIKE (
             '%ab%'  
          OR '%fg%'
          OR '%asd%'
          OR ...
          OR ...
          OR '%kj%'
              )
```

Just looks more comfortable both from a readability point of view and manageability. If the column `Name` changes, I can always make one change instead of a hundred (or using `Find and Replace`). Any suggestions?

Comment: No. BTW: prefixing with LIKE search criteria with a wildcard reduces the usefullness of any available index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to keep repeating the `LIKE`

Although you could probably fool around a bit to make it work something like that, it won't be prettier or more readable.

Perhaps you should generate the query programmatically instead of manually writing this?

PS: perhaps a fulltext index is a better idea here?

Comment: Great! Thanks for the suggestion. Will accept this as the answer after the time limit.

Comment: @Legend: do note that with a `LIKE '%...'` query (i.e. beginning with `%` you cannot use indexes so it will be a slow query. You should really consider using a fulltext search :)

Answer (score 2):

You can put the values in a table, perhaps a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), and semijoin to your table e.g.

```
WITH params 
     AS 
     (
      SELECT * 
        FROM (
              VALUES ('at'),
                     ('fg'),
                     ('asd'),
                     ('kj')
             ) AS T (param)
     )
SELECT *
  FROM Sample.dbo.Temp T
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT *
                 FROM params P
                WHERE T.Name LIKE '%' + P.param + '%'
              );
```

That looks long winded but if the CTE was instead a base table them the query could be data-driven i.e. if the list of parameter values need to change in the future then it would involve merely updating a table rather than amending hard-coded values (possibly in multiple objects).

Comment: + 1. I like this solution, I think you can get a slightly better performance if you include the % in param instead of adding it for each join.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk: that sounds logical and promising but would need to be tested.